# Access elements of a static fixed size array from a DLL in another DLL in Rust

Tags: dll, rust, shared-libraries, ffi

I'm compiling some information of an object into an `.so`, like:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub static a: [f32; 10] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0];
```

(simplified of course)

I need to have access to its values from another `.so` and thinking on simplifying the process, instead of creating a function that returns a `Vec<f32>` for example, I want to return a fixed size array since this will not change, like:

```
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};
...

unsafe {

        let lib = Library::new("path/to/lib.so").unwrap();

        let a: Symbol< * mut [f32; 10] > = lib.get(b"a\0").unwrap();

        println!("{:?}", **a); // To check what is being retrieved

    }
...
```

So far the output being printed is:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Which is correct, but I cannot access it's elements, like:

```
let b = a[0];
```

When compiling:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `libloading::Symbol<'_, *mut [f32; 10]>`
```

How to have access to the values or even assign the whole array to a new one in the caller `.so`?

Comment: You probably need to dereference the symbol manually. Something like: `let b = a.deref()[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the elements, you will have to dereference the `Symbol` and the mutable pointer first, like you already correctly did when printing the full array.

So if you want to access only the first element you will have to use `(**a)[0]` or `(**a)[7]` if you want to retrieve the eigth element.

Here is the full example based on the code in your question:

```rust
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let lib = Library::new("libarray_lib.dylib").unwrap();

        let a: Symbol< * mut [f32; 10] > = lib.get(b"a\0").unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", **a); // To check what is being retrieved
        println!("{}", (**a)[0]); // Dereference a and access its first element

    }
}
```